# How to convert a vector to a list in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I tried this

```
koan-engine.runner=> (map identity [1 2 3])
(1 2 3)
koan-engine.runner=> (type (map identity [1 2 3]))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
koan-engine.runner=> (type '(1 2 3))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

but it just look like a list, actually it is a LazySeq, so how to convert the vector to a list?

Comment: Please, refer to http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Collections and http://clojure.org/reference/sequences to get a better understanding of Clojure collection types.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl thanks.

Comment: The big question is: Why would you ? What operation would you want to do on that list that you couldn't do on a vector ?

Comment: You can call seq on vector like so (seq [1 2 3]) it returns (1 2 3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
user=> (apply list [1 2 3])
(1 2 3)
user=> (type (apply list [1 2 3]))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

`list` creates a list, so you just need to `apply` it to the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into#example-542692cbc026201cdc326baf):

```
user=> (into '() [1 2 3])
(3 2 1)
user=> (type (into '() [1 2 3]))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (into '() (reverse [1 2 3]))
(1 2 3)
user=> (type (into '() (reverse [1 2 3])))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

See also [Creating a List from an Existing Data Structure - Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-02_creating-a-list-from-existing.asciidoc#creating-a-list-from-an-existing-data-structure).